# Is there a way to persist inflight messages on Camel shutdown, and reload on subsequent start?

Tags: java, apache-camel

We would like to leverage Camel to manage sending HTTP requests to external services.  Part of this effort is to retry sending failed messages (target server outages, general internet outages, etc).  We can easily accomplish this (which is awesome!) by setting a retry policy on an error handler in our Camel route.

However the exponential redelivery delay we would like to eventually reach is far beyond an acceptable graceful shutdown period.  For the purposes of deploys, we want to shutdown the service within a shortish period (~60s).  This leaves the possibility of having inflight retry messages.

Is there any way that Camel is able to persist inflight messages on shutdown, and then load back once the system has been started?  I've looked about and it seems like we may have to implement our own InflightRepository and/or LifecycleStrategy, however I figured I'd be best to ask before we started down that seemingly involved path.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem?

Comment: I had forgot about this question. In short, no. I just ended up cobbling together external storages (queues, transient dbs) to help minimize if a microservice went down. It wasn't perfect but it got us to a good enough point.

Answer (score 0):

Camel does support the [Guaranteed Delivery pattern](http://camel.apache.org/guaranteed-delivery.html). The [jms component](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) by default uses persisted delivery